# How to do route constraints in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, subdomain, ruby-on-rails-4

This is not working:

```
get '/' => 'addresses#show', :constraints => Subdomain
```

lib/subdomain.rb:

```
class Subdomain  
  def self.matches?(request)  
    request.subdomain.present? && request.subdomain != 'www'  
  end  
end
```

this route is just ignored...

thank you

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:**

the specified route has to go before

```
root to: 'home#index'
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked perfectly only you need to add subdomain.rb in you routes manually

```
get '/' => 'addresses#show', :constraints => Subdomain
```

lib/subdomain.rb:

```
class Subdomain  
  def self.matches?(request)  
    request.subdomain.present? && request.subdomain != 'www'  
  end  
end
```

Add in routes.rb

```
  require 'subdomain'
```

And yes the specified route has to go before

```
root to: 'home#index'
```